# How to wrap a div container around other div container with height:auto;

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a div container with `height:auto` so as to not limit the whole layout.

However inside the container I have a couple of other containers which some have fixed height and auto height.

```
div.profile_box{
  width:1000px;
  height:auto;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 150px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-500px;
  border:1px solid gray;
}

div.profile_box div.profile_pic{
  position:absolute;
  width:250px;
  height:340px;
  border:1px solid gray;
}

div.profile_pic div.picture{
  position:absolute;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  width:230px;
  height:180px;
  border:1px solid gray;
}

div.activity_all div.blog{
  margin: 20px 5px 5px 5px;
  width:480px;
  height:auto;
  border:1px solid gray;
}

div.activity_all div.photo_album{
  margin: 20px 5px 5px 5px;
  width:650px;
  height:auto;
  border:1px solid gray;
}
```

This is suppose to wrap around all the div-s, however it only appears as a straight thin line on top of all my div-s.

Although all my other divs fall right in the place.

Comment: hard to tell without seeing the html markup, but my first guess is that the `position:absolute` is causing you trouble: this takes the elements out of the layout, so their height won't influence their containing elements.

Answer (score 1):

add `overflow: hidden` to your wrapper and since you have a lot of absolute positioned elements - `position: relative`

Comment: Agreed; the OP might be interested in knowing why they need to do this, too.

Comment: I'm guessing this answer is correct, though, @3cross, you really should provide some html code for us to look at.

Comment: hm this actually hide all my div box. But thanks to ptriek , i realise i have position:absolute in my inner div which make them out of the first wrapper

Comment: then you have to really show us some HTML, so we'll be able to answer without guessing